# Looking for an image carousel-type application

Tags: android, web-apps, ipad-app

I am looking for an image-carousel type application which supports 'like/dislike' functionality for gathering customer input on what types of product they like.

Ideally it will be web enabled, or it can be a standalone app - but either way, think of it as 'tinder for photos of the products that I define'.

Has anyone come across anything like this?